# Spring JPA ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException and not using batch inserts/update

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, optimistic-locking

To give you the context about the issue I am facing, this is a customer table in a Postgres database and its status is update by EventHandler which picks up events from a single SQS queue. This error comes up

```
ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException
Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update customer set created_by=?, lock_id=?, modifiedat=?, modified_by=?, app_id=?, client=?, comments=?, customer_id=?, decision=?, source=? where id=? and lock_id=?; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update customer set created_by=?, lock_id=?, modifiedat=?, modified_by=?, application_id=?, client_app=?, comments=?, customer_id=?, decision=?, source=? where id=? and lock_id=?
```

Now this error shows that batch update is happening but nowhere in this function I am doing batch updates. The code where this insert happens is

```java
public Customer updateOrCreateCustomer(int customerId, String applicationId, String status) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findByCustomerId(customerId);

        if(customer == null) {
            customer = new Customer();
            customer.setCustomerId(customerId);
            customer.setApplicationId(applicationId);
            customer.status(status);
            log.info("Creating Customer with Customer Id - {} Application Id - {}", customerId, applicationId);
        } else {
            customer.setStatus(status);
            log.info("Updating Customer with Customer Id - {} Application Id - {}", customerId, applicationId);
        }
        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
```

Also, in my `application.yml`, I have set the `batch_size` property of JPA to 50 but this is being used in a different API where I need to do batch inserts

```
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      generate_statistics: false
      hibernate:
        order_inserts: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 50
```

I don't know why JPA is doing batch updates in `updateOrCreateCustomer` function. What I guess is that many requests are coming at the same time so JPA sees that batch_size is set, so it automatically combines all these queries into one to optimize inserts/updates and does that. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think  if your object is modified in another thread, and then you try to commit that same object from another thread at the same time, you maybe get ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException
The solution I know is to raise the separation level so that the items are commited one by one and there is no synchronization error.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ)
```

Comment: Is this annotation used in repository functions or general functions of services?

Comment: We can use @Transactional to wrap a method in a database transaction and it allows us to set propagation, isolation, timeout, read-only, and rollback conditions for our transaction. you can use it in Service ,if your function call different repository methods